# How do I create an app-specific password for iCloud?

Tags: icloud, security, apple-id

I'm trying to try out [BusyCal](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/busycal/id1173663647?mt=12), but it requires an app-specific password, and provides [an outdated link to old information about how to do this](https://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT204397).

The page refers to an "App Specific Passwords section" under the Security settings of the [Apple ID site's account management page](https://appleid.apple.com/account/home).  This section does not exist under Security, or anywhere else on that page.

There is almost certainly still a way to create app-specific passwords, but even Apple can't keep their help up-to-date, and even a company whose main product depends on users finding this information can't provide it, so Stack Exchange seemed like the best place to turn.

How (and *where*) do I create an app-specific password these days?

Comment: The screed doesn't help, especially since it's demonstrably wrong.

Comment: Do you have two-factor authentication or [two-step verification](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152) turned on for your Apple ID? If not, you cannot generate app-specific passwords, because they're irrelevant (just use the account's single password).

Comment: @GordonDavisson That is not correct.  App-specific passwords are intended for non-Apple services, and Apple's 2FA does not apply.  Myself, I have three current app-specific passwords... among them one for BusyCal amusingly enough.

Comment: @MarcWilson I'm pretty sure you have two-factor authentication turned on for your Apple ID. As it says in [HT204397](https://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT204397): "To generate and use app-specific passwords, your Apple ID must be protected with two-factor authentication." App-specific passwords are intended to allow Apple IDs that are set to require two-factor (or two-step) auth to be used by client software that doesn't natively support that Apple's 2FA (e.g. BusyCal).

Comment: @GordonDavisson You know, I read "if not", as "if so".  Please allow me to take my foot out of my mouth.

Comment: @MarcWilson: it's demonstrably true. Do you need screenshots?  And I don't know what "screed" you're talking about.  Your rude accusation of falsehood is what doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing information was provided by @GordonDavisson (and if he wants to post an answer I will accept his instead of mine):

> To generate and use app-specific passwords, your Apple ID must be protected with two-factor authentication.

This is actually on the Apple Help page, but oddly *not* included in the section **"How to generate an app-specific password"** (even though it was the missing step for exactly that question) but instead buried between an explanation of *what an app-specific password **is*** (which was of no value to me) and fine print about different OS versions.   I used the headers to skip right to the relevant information (which is what headers are generally for) and didn't guess that a critical piece of information would be placed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It does exist, exactly where the not-outdated-at-all help information says it is.

The support article you link says:

> Sign in to your Apple ID account page.
>   In the Security section, click Generate Password below App-Specific Passwords.
>   Follow the steps on your screen.
>   After you generate your app-specific password, enter or paste it into the password field of the app as you would normally.

Doing this leads you to a page that looks like this:

[image: screenshot of security options]

And there you can create all the app-specific passwords you like.

Comment: It only looks that way _because you already had 2FA enabled_.

Answer (score 0):

You must have Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) enabled in order to create app-specific passwords. Guide here: [How to Use Apple One-Time (App-Specific) Password](https://www.cyclonis.com/how-use-apple-one-time-app-specific-password-protect-id-data/)